# Probabilities of three events inequality check

Tags: probability

We know that $P(A U B U C)$ = $P(A)$ +$P(B)$ + $P(C)$ - P($A \cap B $) -P($B \cap C$) -P($A \cap C$) +P($A \cap B \cap C$) for three events which may/may not be dependent . Can we establish this inequality ? $P(A U B U C)$  $\leq$ $P(A)$ +$P(B)$ + $P(C)$ , what i thought was this is not guaranteed because we might have a situation where  P($A \cap B $) +P($B \cap C$) -P($A \cap C$) +P($A \cap B \cap C$) $\leq 0$ ? I am asking because it was used here  [Probability inequalities for 3 events](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4267120/1021792) and would like to know if anything is wrong

Comment: $P(\bigcup A_n) \leq \sum P(A_n)$ for any sequence of events $A_1,A_2,...$

Comment: Yeah i mean i was trying to show that for the proof of that :the intersection inequality which i am trying to get negative , will never happen at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$P(A \cap B ) +P(B \cap C) +P(A \cap C) -P(A \cap B \cap C)$ cannot be negative because the first two terms are non-negative and  $P(A \cap C) -P(A \cap B \cap C) \geq 0$ too: $P(A \cap B \cap C) \leq P(A\cap C)$.